# Find and replace current cell value with cell number

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm very new to VBA.  I've tried recording my Macro and still can't seem to figure it out.

I want the macro to the following:

On the selected cell I want to search the value and replace what is found by the selected cell "number".

Example : Say I select Cell A1 and its value is 666 I want it to search and replace all Cells on the sheet that contain 666 with "=A1".

In essence I want them all to point to the initial cell.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you loop through the cells in the used range on the current sheet and replace the cell values. Below is the code that will do what you're after. I commented each line to make clear what exactly is happening.

```
Sub Test()
'Range variable to use for looping
Dim rng As Range 

'String variable for finding the values.
Dim searchvalue As String 

'We'll loop on the current sheet
With ActiveSheet

    'You need to have a single cell selected, if that's not the case we exit the macro.
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 

    'Get the value to search for
    searchvalue = Selection.value 

    'Loop over all cells in the sheet that have values.
    For Each rng In .UsedRange 

        'We do not want to overwrite the range from where we search (the selection)
        If Intersect(rng, Selection) Is Nothing Then 

             'And if we find the value that was in the selection
            If rng.value = searchvalue Then

                Then create the =cell we selected formula.
                rng.value = "=" & Selection.Address '
            End If
        End If

    'Next cell in the loop
    Next rng

'And we don't need the activesheet anymore.
End With
End Sub
```

Since this is quite generic stuff, I'd suggest you read up on Excel VBA programming in general. Some great resources are:

- [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA)
- [Rondebruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/) his website
- [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/topic.aspx) his website

Comment: Generic or not, this is not so simple to grasp for the uninitiated.  Nonetheless, thank you very much, it has accomplished exactly what I needed.  Merci!